# D3 grid lines and tick values issues

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have a stacked area chart made using D3. I am facing two issues with my implementation.

1) i just want to display alternative tick values on the y axis. For example in my implementation y axis values are `0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100` and so on. But i want to show values likes `0, 40, 80, 120` but also keeping corresponding grid line. i just want to remove alternative tick value without removing the y-axis grid line.

2) i want to format the y-axis, so that it should always have upper y-axis grid line. So in my implementation i wish to have a grid line above `180` value.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var z = d3.scale.category20c();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")


var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y).innerTickSize(-width).outerTickSize(0)
  .orient("left");

var stack = d3.layout.stack()
  .offset("zero")
  .values(function(d) {
    return d.data;
  })
  .x(function(d) {
    return new Date(d[0]);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d[1];
  });



var area = d3.svg.area()
  .interpolate("cardinal")
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(new Date(d[0]));;
  })
  .y0(function(d) {
    return y(d.y0);
  })
  .y1(function(d) {
    return y(d.y0 + d.y);
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var b = [{
  data: [
    ["2016-01-20T05:31:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:31:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:32:17.000Z", 95.4, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:32:47.000Z", 96.1, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:33:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:33:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:34:17.000Z", 95.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:34:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:35:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:35:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:36:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:36:47.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:37:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:37:47.000Z", 95.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:38:17.000Z", 95.4, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:38:47.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:39:17.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:39:47.000Z", 96.1, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:40:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:40:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:41:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:41:47.000Z", 94.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:42:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:42:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:43:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:43:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:44:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:44:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:45:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:45:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:46:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:46:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:47:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:47:47.000Z", 96.2, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:48:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:48:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:49:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:49:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:50:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:50:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:51:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:51:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:52:18.000Z", 95.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:52:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:53:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:53:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:54:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:54:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:55:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:55:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:56:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:56:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:57:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:57:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:58:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:58:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:59:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:59:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:00:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:00:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:01:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:01:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:02:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:02:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:03:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:03:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:04:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:04:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:05:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:05:48.000Z", 95.7, {}]
  ],
  label: "a"
}, {
  data: [
    ["2016-01-20T05:31:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:31:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:32:17.000Z", 95.4, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:32:47.000Z", 96.1, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:33:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:33:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:34:17.000Z", 95.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:34:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:35:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:35:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:36:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:36:47.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:37:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:37:47.000Z", 95.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:38:17.000Z", 95.4, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:38:47.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:39:17.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:39:47.000Z", 96.1, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:40:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:40:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:41:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:41:47.000Z", 94.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:42:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:42:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:43:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:43:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:44:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:44:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:45:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:45:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:46:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:46:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:47:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:47:47.000Z", 96.2, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:48:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:48:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:49:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:49:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:50:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:50:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:51:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:51:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:52:18.000Z", 95.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:52:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:53:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:53:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:54:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:54:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:55:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:55:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:56:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:56:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:57:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:57:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:58:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:58:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:59:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:59:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:00:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:00:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:01:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:01:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:02:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:02:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:03:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:03:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:04:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:04:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:05:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:05:48.000Z", 95.7, {}]
  ],
  label: "b"
}]




var layers = stack(b);

var ary = [];
layers.forEach(function(d) {
  ary.push(d.data)
})

x.domain(d3.extent(d3.merge(ary), function(d) {
  return new Date(d[0]);
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(d3.merge(ary), function(d) {
  return d.y0 + d.y;
})]);


svg.selectAll(".layer")
  .data(layers)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "layer")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return area(d.data);
  })
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return z(i);
  });

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

**NOTE:** Data values are dynamic, so y-axis tick values are not fixed. Please help me find a solution which can be applicable on any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make tick values do:

```
var max = y.domain()[1];
var values = [];
for(var j =0; j <=max; j=j+20){
    values.push(j)
}
values.push(max)

yAxis.tickValues(values);
```

To hide alternate grid text do:

```
var last = svg.selectAll(".y .tick text")[0].length;  

svg.selectAll(".y .tick text")[0].forEach(function(d, i){
  if (i==last-1){
    return;//for showing last tick
  }
  if(i%2==0)
    d3.select(d).style("display", "none");//for showing alternate ticks
});
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8MNaJOCMeY31yD8Tilma?p=preview)

Comment: Thank You for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Both your requirement are easily addressed by setting parameters of your `yAxis`.

1. Custom tick values can be specified by using [`axis.tickValues()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickValues) overriding the ones provided by the scale's automatic tick generator. For your case this means calling `yAxis.tickValues([0, 40, 80, 120])`. To hide certain tick values while still drawing the grid lines, you may use [`axis.tickFormat()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat) which – depending on your logic – needs to return an empty string for every tick values to be omitted. The example below will display every second tick values, but feel free to implement any logic to your liking.
2. If you want an enclosing grid line above the diagram, you could use [`yAxis.outerTickSize(-width)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#outerTickSize) which will add grid lines at the min/max values of the scale's extent much like the inner ones are added for intermediate values. Note, however, that this will, as a side-effect, also add a grid line at the lower end of the y-axis, which doesn't hurt in your case, because it will be the same as your x-axis.

The code for generating the `yAxis` will look something like this:

```
var yTicks = [40,80,120,160];               // Use whatever values you like.
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .innerTickSize(-width)
  .outerTickSize(-width)                    // Set to -width for upper/lower grid lines
  .tickValues(yTicks)                       // Set custom grid values.
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return yTicks.indexOf(d) % 2 ? d : "";  // Custom tickFormat to hide certain tickValues
  })
  .orient("left");
```

If you don't want the upper grid line to be flush with the values' path, you may add a little padding by extending the scale's domain:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(d3.merge(ary), function(d) {
  return d.y0 + d.y;
}) * 1.1]);   // Extending the extent's max value by .1 to allow for padding.
```

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var z = d3.scale.category20c();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")

var yTicks = [40,80,120,160];               // Use whatever values you like.
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .innerTickSize(-width)
  .outerTickSize(-width)                    // Set to -width for upper/lower grid lines
  .tickValues(yTicks)                       // Set custom grid values.
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return yTicks.indexOf(d) % 2 ? d : "";  // Use a custom tickFormat to hide certain tickValues
  })
  .orient("left");

var stack = d3.layout.stack()
  .offset("zero")
  .values(function(d) {
    return d.data;
  })
  .x(function(d) {
    return new Date(d[0]);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d[1];
  });



var area = d3.svg.area()
  .interpolate("cardinal")
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(new Date(d[0]));;
  })
  .y0(function(d) {
    return y(d.y0);
  })
  .y1(function(d) {
    return y(d.y0 + d.y);
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var b = [{
  data: [
    ["2016-01-20T05:31:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:31:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:32:17.000Z", 95.4, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:32:47.000Z", 96.1, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:33:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:33:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:34:17.000Z", 95.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:34:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:35:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:35:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:36:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:36:47.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:37:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:37:47.000Z", 95.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:38:17.000Z", 95.4, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:38:47.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:39:17.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:39:47.000Z", 96.1, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:40:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:40:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:41:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:41:47.000Z", 94.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:42:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:42:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:43:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:43:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:44:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:44:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:45:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:45:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:46:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:46:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:47:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:47:47.000Z", 96.2, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:48:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:48:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:49:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:49:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:50:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:50:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:51:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:51:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:52:18.000Z", 95.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:52:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:53:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:53:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:54:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:54:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:55:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:55:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:56:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:56:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:57:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:57:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:58:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:58:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:59:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:59:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:00:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:00:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:01:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:01:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:02:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:02:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:03:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:03:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:04:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:04:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:05:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:05:48.000Z", 95.7, {}]
  ],
  label: "a"
}, {
  data: [
    ["2016-01-20T05:31:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:31:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:32:17.000Z", 95.4, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:32:47.000Z", 96.1, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:33:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:33:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:34:17.000Z", 95.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:34:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:35:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:35:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:36:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:36:47.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:37:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:37:47.000Z", 95.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:38:17.000Z", 95.4, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:38:47.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:39:17.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:39:47.000Z", 96.1, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:40:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:40:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:41:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:41:47.000Z", 94.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:42:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:42:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:43:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:43:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:44:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:44:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:45:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:45:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:46:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:46:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:47:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:47:47.000Z", 96.2, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:48:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:48:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:49:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:49:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:50:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:50:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:51:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:51:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:52:18.000Z", 95.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:52:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:53:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:53:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:54:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:54:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:55:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:55:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:56:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:56:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:57:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:57:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:58:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:58:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:59:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:59:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:00:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:00:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:01:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:01:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:02:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:02:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:03:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:03:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:04:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:04:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:05:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:05:48.000Z", 95.7, {}]
  ],
  label: "b"
}]




var layers = stack(b);

var ary = [];
layers.forEach(function(d) {
  ary.push(d.data)
})

x.domain(d3.extent(d3.merge(ary), function(d) {
  return new Date(d[0]);
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(d3.merge(ary), function(d) {
  return d.y0 + d.y;
}) * 1.1]);   // Extending the extent's max value by .1 to allow for padding.

svg.selectAll(".layer")
  .data(layers)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "layer")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return area(d.data);
  })
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return z(i);
  });

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Data is not fixed. The tick values of y axis will change according to data from the backend. Please help me find a generic solution which don't need to specify the `tickValues` manually. Also i don't want the corresponding grid line to disappear. In your solution for the first issue, when you are removing the `20` from the y-axis, the corresponding grid line is also getting removed but i want that grid line to be there but not the tick.

Comment: You could pass in any array of tick values you like. Of course, you could pre-calculate this array depending on how many grid lines you want. They won't even need to be evenly spaced; `[1,5,10,20,50,500]` will be perfectly fine. I am not sure how this could be more dynamic. I had just borrowed the array you provided in your question.

Comment: How can i pre-calculate this array?

Comment: Basically i want to draw grid lines between two ticks and not able to do so. Can you help me?

Comment: I have updated my answer to better fit your requirements.